# Compiling and Executing Java file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I open an java file in python?, i've search over the net and found this:

```
import os.path, subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT, PIPE

def compile_java (java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java (java_file):
    cmd=['java', java_file]
    proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
    input = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = PIPE)
    print(proc.stdout.read())

compile_java("CsMain.java")
execute_java("CsMain")
```

but then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\casestudy\opener.py", line 13, in <module>
    compile_java("CsMain.java")
  File "C:\casestudy\opener.py", line 5, in compile_java
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 539, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 520, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 820, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

the python file and java file is in the same folder, and I am using Python 3.3.2, how can I resolve this? or do you guys have another way on doing this?, any answer is appreciated thanks!

Comment: please post the traceback as text, not an image

Comment: ok im editing it, sorry for that, but can I know why? sorry i'm new here.

Comment: mainly for searchability

Comment: Is "javac" in your path?  From where you're executing the python code, can you also run "javac -version" successfully?

Comment: @sdanzig how can I run javac -version? i've tried editing the 'javac' to 'javac -version' and didn't work, im executing the python code in C:\casestudy

Comment: I meant running it at the command line.  At the command prompt, just typing "javac -version".  If it says "command not found", that's you're problem.  To add it to the path, you need to find out where you installed Java.  If you just installed a JRE rather than a JDK, then you won't have javac anywhere, and you'll need to install a JDK.  Here's something on how to set the path in Windows: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: @sdanzig I just noticed you were helping with the same advice up here. We even used the same link...

Comment: @sdanzig I've installed jdk1.7.0_11 in my laptop and I can compile and run my java program without problem in my cmd, I also changed the Path of my System variables into the path of the JDK bin as what is Jaws212 said but again the same problem showed up in my python code.

Comment: Did you open a new terminal/command window?  You need to, in order to get the new path to take effect.  Also, in your System variables path, you may have to put quotes around the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin ... because of that space in Program Files.  Basically, if "javac -version" runs in the same window, just before you type something to run the python code, then we can likely eliminate your path as a factor.

Comment: It works now!, I've added some codes earlier and I think that it is not working, but then I re-open my python code and it works, I think that your advice about changing the path also helps me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it isn't recognizing the `javac` command. Try manually running the command and if `javac` isn't a recognized command, register it in your `PATH` variable and try again.

Or you could just try typing the full pathname to the Java directory for `javac` and `java`.

Comment: how can I register it in PATH variable?, i've tried typing the full path name to the directory and got the same error, and also adding parameter for javac and java doesn't work too

Comment: The path to `java` and `javac` will be something like `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin'`. The version may be different depending on which you have installed. Simply edit the PATH variable by adding a `;` then the path to java's bin folder. If you don't know how to access the PATH variable, go here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm.

However, if typing the path to Java's bin directory in the command (i.e. `subprocess.check_call(['C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac', java_file])`) didn't work, then it may not be the issue.

Comment: hello I append into the path in my system variables this C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin and tried to run my java program in the cmd and javac is recognized, the programs runs without problems and I also tried running again my python code and again the same error showed up

Comment: Well I'm at a loss then. It looks very much like a PATH issue. I tested in Python 3.3 and 2.7, both worked just fine. I also tried removing the entry from my PATH variable and I got the error you did. However, I just tested putting the exact path to javac and java into the code and it failed, it seems I was mistaken. Presumably it fails because there is a space in the path name (so the system thinks that `C:\Program` should be a command).

Comment: It works now!, I've added some codes earlier and I think that it is not working, but then I re-open my python code and it works, I think that your advice about changing the path also helps me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `path` to your java file name. like this:

```
compile_java("C:\\path\to\this\CsMain.java")
```